# Invalid interger value (Unable to store value into database)

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

I would like to ask.I am having trouble where i could not get the id instead I am getting the whole row.

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $leave = $request->get('leave');
        $leave['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        $leave['status_id']= StatusType::find(1);
        $leave = Leave::create($leave);

        return Redirect::to(route('leave.create'));
    }
```

The error showed was

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{"id":1,"status":"Pending","created_at":"2020-03-12 08:40:14","updated_at":"2020-03-12 08:40:14"}' for column 'status_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `leaves` (`type_id`, `start`, `end`, `remarks`, `user_id`, `status_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2020-03-13, 2020-03-14, test, 2, `{"id":1,"status":"Pending","created_at":"2020-03-12 08:40:14","updated_at":"2020-03-12 08:40:14"}`, 2020-03-13 07:58:17, 2020-03-13 07:58:17))

I only need to get the id instead of the whole row. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is returning whole `$leave` object:

```
$leave['status_id']= StatusType::find(1);
```

And your `status_id` field is probably integer. So you need to change it like this:

```
$leave['status_id']= StatusType::find(1)->id;
```

Which will give you an ouput of integer.

More on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

Answer (score 2):

`StatusType::find(1)` will gives you object not integer value.
Now only the change add `column_name` as `StatusType::find(1)->column_name`

Try as below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $leave = $request->get('leave');
        $leave['user_id'] = Auth::id();
        $leave['status_id']= StatusType::find(1)->id ?? 0;
        $leave = Leave::create($leave);

        return Redirect::to(route('leave.create'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of column 'id' from that single row as such:

```
$StatusType::find(1)->id;
```

Reference: ["Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table"](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries)